# Laravel carga las imagenes en la base de datos pero no en la pagina web

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-blade

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]este es el controlador de imagenes ImageController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Product;
use App\ProductImage;

class ImageController extends Controller
{
    public function index($id)
    {
      $product = Product::find($id);
      $images = $product->images;
      return view('admin.products.images.index')->with(compact('product', 'images'));
    }

    public function store(Request $request, $id)
    {
      //guardar la imagen en nuestro proyecto
      $file = $request->file('photo');
      $path = public_path() . '/images/products';
      $fileName = uniqid() . $file->getClientOriginalName();
      $file->move($path, $fileName);

      //crear 1 registro en la tabla product_images
      $productImage = new ProductImage();
      $productImage->image = $fileName;
      //$productImage->featured = false;
      $productImage->product_id = $id;
      $productImage->save(); //INSERT

      return back();
    }

    public function destroy()
    {

    }
}
```

Esta es la vista de las imagenes

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('title', 'Imágenes de producto')

@section('body-class', 'landing-page sidebar-collapse')

@section('content')
<div class="header header-filter" style="background-image: url('{{ asset('img/profile_city.jpg') }}'); height: 300px;">
</div>
<div class="main main-raised">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="section text-center">
            <h2 class="title">Imágenes del producto "{{ $product->name }}"</h2>
            <div style="display: block; margin: 30px auto;">
              <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                {{ csrf_field() }}
                <label class="btn btn-primary btn-round" for="photo">Elige una imagen</label>
                <input class="file" type="file" id="photo" name="photo" required>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-round">Subir nueva imagen</button>
                <a href="{{ url('/admin/products') }}" class="btn btn-default btn-round">Cancelar</a>
              </form>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
            @foreach($images as $image)
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-body" style="margin-bottom: 30px;">
                  <img src="{{ $image->url }}" class="rounded mx-auto d-block">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-round">Eliminar</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            @endforeach
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@include('includes.footer')
@endsection
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que no funciona en el código?

Comment: no me da ningun error pero si un enlace roto de la imagen en la pagina un 404 de que no encuentra la imagen pero verifique en phpmyadmin y si esta cargada la imagen, no se que pasa.

Comment: sería mejor que agregues el código de la vista para verificar lo que mencionas

Comment: ya añadi las ediciones como ves en la imagen las imagenes autogeneradas de pexels.com si cargan pero la que decidi cargar yo "manualmente" tiene el enlace roto

Comment: deberia agregar algo más en mi edición para facilitarles ver mi codigo? puedo pegar el enlace de github https://github.com/PequeCeci/shopp-app ya la subi aqui.

Comment: si ya es src="/images/products/5c5c345c7caf6gato.jpg"

Comment: ya subi otra imagen para mostrar el inspector

Comment: ¿ya verificaste en qué ruta está almacenada como tal?

Comment: los errores que dice son dos y dicen "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)" y el otro "js?key=YOUR_KEY_HERE:51 Google Maps JavaScript API error: InvalidKeyMapError"

Comment: verificaste permisos de escritura en la carpeta? es decir: el archivo se graba en disco además de en la db?

Comment: como verifico en que ruta esta almacenada como tal? en phpmyadmin estan las mismas rutas no se que puede estar pasando

Comment: en que carpeta verifico los permisos de escritura?

Comment: Vuelvo y pregunto: ¿En qué ruta (carpeta) están almacenadas como tal las imágenes?

Comment: estan en public/images/products

Comment: seria buena para la proxima publicar tambien una imagen del inspector del navegador para ver lo que esta ejecutando!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

puedes hacerlo asi:

```
public function store(Request $request, $id)
{
  //guardar la imagen en nuestro proyecto
  $file = $request->file('photo');
  $path = public_path('/images/products/');
  $fileName = uniqid() . $file->getClientOriginalName();
  $file->move($path, $fileName);

  //crear 1 registro en la tabla product_images
  $productImage = new ProductImage();
  $productImage->image = $fileName;
  //$productImage->featured = false;
  $productImage->product_id = $id;
  $productImage->save(); //INSERT

  return back();
}
```

ahora el views

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('title', 'Imágenes de producto')

@section('body-class', 'landing-page sidebar-collapse')

@section('content')
<div class="header header-filter" style="background-image: url('{{ asset('img/profile_city.jpg') }}'); height: 300px;">
</div>
<div class="main main-raised">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="section text-center">
            <h2 class="title">Imágenes del producto "{{ $product->name }}"</h2>
            <div style="display: block; margin: 30px auto;">
              <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                {{ csrf_field() }}
                <label class="btn btn-primary btn-round" for="photo">Elige una imagen</label>
                <input class="file" type="file" id="photo" name="photo" required>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-round">Subir nueva imagen</button>
                <a href="{{ url('/admin/products') }}" class="btn btn-default btn-round">Cancelar</a>
              </form>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
            @foreach($images as $image)
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-body" style="margin-bottom: 30px;">
                  <img src="{{URL::to('/')}}/images/products/{{ $image->url }}" class="rounded mx-auto d-block">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-round">Eliminar</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            @endforeach
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@include('includes.footer')
@endsection
```

Comment: si lo hago asi no me carga ni una sola imagen D:

Comment: tampoco las de pexel.com

Comment: coloca una imagen de tu inspector de codigo.. click derecho sobre una imagen inspeccionar!

Comment: <img src="/images/products/5c5c33d36dcbcgato.jpg" class="rounded mx-auto d-block"> eso es lo que me aparece en el inspector

Comment: ya corregin intenta ahora!

Comment: No tampoco se ve ni una imagen :(

Comment: y el inspector?? que muestra ahora?

Comment: el inspector muestra esto <img src="http://shopp/public/images/products//images/products/5c5c345c7caf6gato.jpg" class="rounded mx-auto d-block">

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89406/discussion-between-bryro-and-cecipeque).

Comment: mil gracias @Bryro